# x:Type in Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, types, ivalueconverter

In a WPF Application I can use x:Type, e.g. for ConverterParameter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedParty.Firstname}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedParty,Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type model:PersonParty}}"/>
```

In a Windows Phone 8 App "x:Type" is unavailable! How can I pass a type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the object as the parameter and then determine it's type in the converter.

This would therefore mean you're creating a "PartyToVisibility" converter but just basing the logic on the type of the party.